# A little confused about trailing slash behavior in nginx

Tags: nginx

Trailing Slash in nginx has been giving me some sleepless nights lately. Requesting some help with this

**Question** : **Strange trailing slash behavior in `proxy_pass`.**

So why would this work :

```
location /myapi/ {
      proxy_pass   http://node_server8/;
    }
```

and this won't

```
location /myapi/ {
      proxy_pass   http://node_server8;
    }
```

Notice the missing trailing slash at the end of `http://node_server8` in second code block. This is specially strange as I have a few other configurations where I don't have a trailing slash on the backend and all works fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are totally different.

In the first `proxy_pass` statement you have included a URI parameter with a value of `/`. In the second you haven't.

When you give `proxy_pass` a URI parameter (within a prefix `location`), it transforms the requested URI similarly to the `alias` function, whereby the value of the `location` directive is substituted for the value of the URI parameter. For example `/myapi/foo` becomes `/foo` before being passed upstream.

If you do not provide `proxy_pass` with a URI parameter, no transformation takes place, and the request `/myapi/foo` is passed upstream unchanged.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Comment: Thanks Richard. But then how is it that it works just fine without the trailing `/` for some of my other back end nginx configurations... I am probably missing something here.

Comment: The configurations are different and presumably the requirements of the other backends are different too.