# How to serve subdirectory as root in nginx using django?

Tags: python, django, nginx, url-rewriting

When a user visits www.website.com I would like to server content as if the user went to www.website.com/frontend/. However, I want to mask the /frontend/ part of the url so the user doesn't see it. Can this be done?

What would my rewrite rule look like?

SOLVED:

```
location = / {
    rewrite ^/$ /frontend/ last;
}
```

My issue was

```
location = / {} #Matches the path project.example.com only (mind there is a =)
location / {} #Matches every path (mind: there is no =)
```

Comment: All URLs `/some/path` should go to `/frontend/some/path`?

Comment: It should serve the content from my django app as if the user went to /frontend/some/path, correct. But I don't want the user to see /frontend/ in the url, just received the content from /frontend/ app

Comment: Why don't you just include frontend scripts into main page? Why not to use `location = / { ... root /frontend}` ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think using `rewrite` is the perfect solution (by the way i don't think it will cover all aspects of your problem and may cause new problems)

The solution is as follow:

nginx config should be something like this:

```
upstream django {
    server unix://tmp/gunicorn.sock;  //
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <your_app_domain_here>;
    location /frontend {
        include uwsgi_params;
        proxy_pass http://django/;
    }
}
```

or if you are not using `sock` file, you can use http method. for example if you are running django on your localhost with port 8000, then change it to:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
```

**But remember** you should add this in your django `settings.py`. Unless it doesn't work at all:

```
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = "/frontend"
```

By this method, you are changing base url in django. so all django urls should start with `fronted` label. Now nginx can perfectly act as a reverse proxy for your site :)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

```
location = / {
    rewrite ^/$ /frontend/ last;
}
```

My issue was

```
location = / {} #Matches the path project.example.com only (mind there is a =)
location / {} #Matches every path (mind: there is no =)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need rewrite rules for this. Just use

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://<your_backend>/frontend/;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't do anything, unfortunately.  `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80/frontend/`; just returns "Url not found"

Comment: You forgot a trailing slash or this is just a typo?

Comment: Do you remove you rewriting rules before testing this?

Comment: Ya I did. So the only way / works is having `rewrite ^/$ /frontend/ last;`. But now both / works and /frontend/ works, making any link on the page turn the url back into /frontend/

Comment: That is very strange. Your backend defined via IP address or via unix socket?

Comment: Also: do you remove `location = / { ...}` block before testing this?

Comment: I believe IP, but I use uwsgi so maybe unix socket? I'm not sure to be honest. And yeah removed the location block

Comment: I'm sorry, one more question: in your config what directive do you use for passing request to backend? `proxy_pass` or `uwsgi_pass`?

Comment: location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }

Comment: Maybe that is the reason my solution doesn't work. Accroding to documentation [`uwsgi_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html#uwsgi_pass), in contrast of [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass), does not allow to specify an URI with the backend. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53671687/nginx-multiple-django-apps-same-domain-different-urls) question `proxy_pass` with specified URI works fine.