# NGINX proxy pass a portion of the request URL

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I would like to do the following in my NGINX configuration: I want to proxy pass the path and query parameters but not include the first path parameter (path1).

Request URL

`https://my-domain.com/path1/path2?query1=some-query`

I want this to proxy_pass to

`http://localhost:8000/path2?query1=some-query`

I have tried with the following location block

```
location /path1/path2/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8000$request_uri;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
}
```

However, this does not go to the correct endpoint because I think it includes the `path1` parameter too. I have several different `path2` routes and so I want to be able to catch and redirect them all easily - without having to manually define each one like this:

```
location /path1/path2a/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/path2a?query1=some-query;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
}

location /path1/path2b/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/path2b?query1=some-query;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
}

location /path1/path2c/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/path2c?query1=some-query;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
}
```

ADDITIONAL EDIT:

I also cannot simply do

```
location /path1/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
}
```

because I already have the `location /path1/` block that gets upgraded to a WebSocket connection at a different endpoint:

```
location /path1/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
}
```

I have searched a lot online but cannot find a configuration that works for my specific scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really simple:

```
location /path1/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
}
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649885/a-little-confused-about-trailing-slash-behavior-in-nginx) Q/A for details.

### Update

This solution isn't usable after OP clarifies his question.

If all of the additional paths share common suffix `path2`:

```
location /path1/path2 {
    rewrite ^/path1(.*) $1 break; # remove '/path1' URI prefix
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
}
```

If they aren't, replace `location /path1/path2` with `location ~ ^/path1/(?:path2a|path2b|path2c)`.

If you need to pass to the backend query arguments that are different from those came with the request, use

```
set $args query1=some-query;
```

within the location block.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for your comment. I forgot to specify why I also cannot do that. I have just modified the question with an additional note.