# Conditional proxy_pass based on current location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, proxypass

I want to do this

```
location ~ /.*$ {
    proxy_pass http://mysecondapp.local;
}
```

but only if the user is in `/mysecondapp` or in `/mysecondapp/something` and not the root url or anything else.

This is the configuration for /mysecondapp:

```
location /mysecondapp {
    proxy_pass http://mysecondapp.local;
}
```

How can I do that?

I tried to put the first location inside the second one, but that didn't do the trick.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Remove the first location block and leave only the second one.

Comment: But I want to go to http://mysecondapp.local even if the url doesn't include  /mysecondapp but it's coming from /mysecondapp (the referer)

Comment: Location blocks do not work with the `referrer` HTTP header - they only look at the URL path.

Comment: @h_h10a Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62840133/7121513) answer, first example (Using conditional routing based on HTTP `Referer` header value). Be careful - this technique works well only with SPA (single page applications).