# How to configure nginx proxy?

Tags: nginx, proxy, localhost, nginx-reverse-proxy, proxypass

Here is what I need,
when its localhost:80 I need Nginx welcome page to be served, but when its localhost:80/pass, my application(react app) to be served, here is my Nginx.conf looks like,

```
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location /pass {
        root   build;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

am I missing something, because it's serving me this

> An error occurred.
> Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.
> Please try again later.If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should check the error log for details.Faithfully yours, nginx.

here is my error.log

```
2020/09/19 21:54:00 [error] 10888#1388: *35 connect() failed (10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /pass HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:3000/", host: "localhost"

2020/09/19 21:54:39 [error] 10888#1388: *35 connect() failed (10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /pass HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "localhost"
```

Comment: Can you add corresponding error log entries to your question? Also, with this configuration request to `http://localhost/pass` would be passed to your backend as `http://localhost:3000/pass`, not as `http://localhost:3000/`, is this what you expecting?

Comment: ill be just passing ```http://localhost:3000/``` to backend

Comment: Can you post the error logs?

Comment: Try adding trailing slash to your `proxy_pass` directive: `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;`. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649885/a-little-confused-about-trailing-slash-behavior-in-nginx/53650827#53650827) answer for explanation.

Comment: added last 2 error log @NamanArora

Comment: I did that as well @IvanShatsky, didn't work

Comment: I see, your backend refused connection. I think you would need this trailing slash anyway, but your current problem related to something else. Is `http://localhost:3000` accesslible from command line via `curl`?