# How to setup a Nginx reverse proxy for an ASP.NET app URL

Tags: asp.net, nginx, iis, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an ASP.NET based app (on IIS8); which loads perfectly when visiting it directly at: `http://localhost:89/files`

When I visit my ngnix reverse proxy URL: `http://localhost/files`, instead of loading the webpage, the file `Login.aspx` is downloaded by the web browser.  I don't have any issues with reverse proxying the root domain *(for regular HTML webpages)*.

I would like to resolve this issue without modifying my ASP.NET app if at all possible.  Below, is the configuration I'm using in `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   "C:\inetpub\wwwroot";
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /files {
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:89/files/;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

}
```

Maybe, there's something I need to change on my `Web.config` file for the ASP.NET app?

Comment: Try simply the `proxy_pass http://localhost:89;`

Comment: @IvanShatsky, Thank you that worked!!  There's no way I would have guessed that.  I'm so glad I asked here.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649885/a-little-confused-about-trailing-slash-behavior-in-nginx) thread for the explanation.

Comment: Thank you.  @IvanShatsky if you want to post your solution as a Stackoverflow official answer, I can mark it as the Answer.

Comment: Thanks, don't think it worth to be an answer, you'd better upvote the Richard Smith's explanation of `proxy_pass` behavior :)

Comment: Done.  Now I know how to use regex for proxy_pass.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you have sovled it, you can post the solution to help others with similar problem.

Comment: Hi Bruce, I didn't solve it.  @iV

Comment: @BruceZhang, The solution is the first comment here,  I'm not sure if I should answer my own question.