# 401 Unauthorized accessing arango interface behind nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, arangodb, nginx-reverse-proxy

When I'm trying to access the web interface of arangoDb behind a nginx reverse proxy I'm getting a 401 Unauthorized reponse

This is my current nginx configuration

```
location /db/bnf/ {
   auth_basic off;
   proxy_pass http://172.28.1.3:8529/;  
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

The `auth_basic off;` is used here because of I already have security at the root of the server (.htpasswd method) I've tried with and without it

I'm able to access the login page via

```
http://something/db/bnf/_db/_system/_admin/aardvark/index.html#login
```

But then when I'm trying to login for exemple :

```
POST https://something/_db/_system/_open/auth
```

The post url seems wrong to me and should be

```
https://something/db/bnf/_db/_system/_open/auth
```

The arango conf file is set to default. I have read the documentation but they are only talking about Foxx services.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649885/a-little-confused-about-trailing-slash-behavior-in-nginx) Q/A.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

actually there is a way to serve frontend via custom path, I wasn't aware of it as I didn't find it in documentation, but then I dug in code and found issue [respect `x-script-name` header when calculating the initial redirect into aardvark](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/8176)

what you need to do is

- start arangod with `--frontend.trusted-proxy` set to ip of your proxy server
- add in location in nginx conf `proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /db/bnf;`
- access admin ui via full path `/db/bnf/_db/_system/_admin/aardvark/index.html` cause initial redirect doesn't work viz mentioned issue

when all set correctly you'll see your `/db/bnf` under `basePath` in `/_db/_system/_admin/aardvark/config.js`

---

ArangoDB web server serves everything via path starting `/_db/...`, same path is hardcoded in UI, that's why you see that login POST to `/_db/...` and that's why you need change in nginx config your `location /db/bnf/` to `location /_db`

Comment: I get that, but this is not what I want. I'm looking for a way to bypass that either in Arango Web Server conf or using nginx