# Proxy in nginx - forwarding location

Tags: api, nginx, proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

Lets say I have a REST API listening on localhost on the server example.com, and I have the following proxy working in a proxy.conf file:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
}
```

This means I can access my API, e.g. example.com/users. However this setup has caused some conflict, so I instead need it with the location as follows:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
}
```

I can correctly access the root of the API using example.com/api. However, the links it returns are in the context example.com/users etc, not example.com/api/users as I would need.

Essentially I am asking, how do I forward the request to my API with example.com/api/ instead of just example.com?

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649885/a-little-confused-about-trailing-slash-behavior-in-nginx).

Comment: Thank you @IvanShatsky that solved my problem! I've never needed to proxies before, so I wasn't even sure what to search, let alone how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! If anyone comes across this, my solution was as follows:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080; # note the removed trailing /
}
```

Thanks to Ivan for providing [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649885/a-little-confused-about-trailing-slash-behavior-in-nginx) to help!