# How to correctly change the location directive in nginx?

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, falconframework

I implemented a simple REST API using Falcon and running it with Gunicorn. An example call looks like this

```
curl "http://localhost:5000/articles?limit=100"
```

Now I'm trying to make the API accessible using nginx, and I actually got it working using the following config file for nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }
}
```

With this I can go to `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/articles?limit=100` to get the respective response. The only thing I would like to do now is to change the location directive. When I change the config file to

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;

    location /test/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }
}
```

I would assume that `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/test/articles?limit=100` will again give me the correct response, but I get an 404. Using `/test` instead of `/test/` doesn't help either. What am I missing?

Comment: Use `location /test/ { ... proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/; }` (note the trailing slash). Explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649885/a-little-confused-about-trailing-slash-behavior-in-nginx).

Comment: @IvanShatsky thanks so much, that did it! Feel free to submit your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks, but I really don't want to duplicate content already existed on the SO. Meanwhile you can upvote the @RichardSmith answer.